# How do I use Google Analytics API with Zend OAuth?

Tags: api, zend-framework, oauth, google-analytics, analytics

I never write in forums, so I hope I don't break your codex. But I have a question regarding Zend's OAuth features.

I've been trying to use it to get feeds from Google Analytics API, but I just can't get it to work.

I've got the OAuth sign-in working just fine, and I can use it with i.e. Google Docs, no problem. But Zend doesn't yet come with support for Google Analytics.

I'm going to post my code now, and if anyone has a clue about how to get a feed out of Google Analytics using Zend's OAuth features, I'd appreciate it - and the internet is really lacking info on this topic!

Also, I'm writing it as a Wordpress plugin, so disregard all the get_option and update_option etc. Imagine you're using Sessions instead :)

Regards,
Fredrik

EDIT: Oh, and one more thing. Google Analytics uses this kind of URL to get feeds:
https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga%3A0000000&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&start-date=2011-05-09&end-date=2011-05-23&max-results=50

```
   $consumerKey = 'XXX';
   $secret = 'XXX';

   require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
   Zend_Loader::loadClass( 'Zend_Gdata_HttpClient' );
   Zend_Loader::loadClass( 'Zend_Gdata_Docs' );
   Zend_Loader::loadClass( 'Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets' );
   Zend_Loader::loadClass( 'Zend_Oauth_Consumer' );
   Zend_Loader::loadClass( 'Zend_Http_Client' );
   Zend_Loader::loadClass( 'Zend_Gdata_Gbase' );

   // set your Google consumer key / secret 
   $CONSUMER_KEY       = $consumerKey;
   $CONSUMER_SECRET    = $secret;
   $RETURN_TO = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

   // Multi-scoped token.
   // Sorry! I'm using the analytics scope at this particular place in the code. In the bottom of this code though, there's some request code that needs the Google Docs scope. If you want a working example for Google Docs, change this scope accordingly.
   $SCOPES = array(
      'https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/',
   );

   $oauthOptions = array(
      'requestScheme'       => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER,
      'version'             => '1.0',
      'consumerKey'          => $CONSUMER_KEY,
      'consumerSecret'       => $CONSUMER_SECRET,
      'signatureMethod'       => 'HMAC-SHA1',
      'callbackUrl'          => $RETURN_TO,
      'requestTokenUrl'       => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken',
      'userAuthorizationUrl'    => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
      'accessTokenUrl'       => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken'
   );

   if ( trim( $accessToken ) == '' ) {
      $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer( $oauthOptions );

      echo 'yes 1';
      update_option( 'ni_trends_google_request_token', serialize( $consumer->getRequestToken( array( 'scope' => implode( ' ', $SCOPES ) ) ) ) );
      $approvalUrl = $consumer->getRedirectUrl( array( 'hd' => 'default' ) );
      echo '<a href="' . $approvalUrl . '">Grant access</a>';

      if ( trim( $accessToken ) == '' ) {
         update_option( 'ni_trends_google_access_token', serialize( $consumer->getAccessToken( $_GET, unserialize( $requestToken ) ) ) );
      }

      update_option( 'ni_trends_google_request_token', '' );
   }

   $accessToken = unserialize( $accessToken );

   // This is where I run into trouble. This is for Google Docs, and it's working (although I have the Analytics Scope configured at the moment) - but how do I make my request and fetch the feed from Google Analytics?
   $httpClient = $accessToken->getHttpClient($oauthOptions);
   $client = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($httpClient, "yourCompany-YourAppName-v1");
   $feed = $client->getDocumentListFeed();
   echo "<pre>";
   echo "<ul>\n";
   foreach ($feed->entries as $entry) {
      echo "<li>$entry->title </li>\n";
   }
   echo "</ul>\n";
   echo "</pre>\n";
```

EDIT: Solved it with the following!

```
$accessToken = unserialize( $accessToken );

    $client = $accessToken->getHttpClient( $oauthOptions );
    $client->resetParameters();

    $parameters = array(
        'ids' => 'ga:26870853',
        'metrics' => 'ga:pageviews',
        'start-date' => '2010-01-08',
        'end-date' => '2011-05-22',
        'max-results' => '50'
    );

    $client->setUri('https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data');

    $client->setParameterGet($parameters);

    $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET);

    $response = $client->request();

    print_r( $response );

    exit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

https://github.com/danielmitd/Zend_Gdata_Analytics/tree/master/Zend/Gdata

It's not official, but it works perfectly for me.  The original page is down it seems, so I'm not sure how hard the documentation will be to track down.  I can post some examples if needed.

Comment: Examples can be found here: [Zend_Gdata_Analytics](http://healthycod.in/2011/07/google-analytics-and-zend-framework/)